# Is it safe to install .net 4.0 RC on a 3.5 development machine?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, .net-4.0, compatibility

I want to try a few things with the new version of the framework, but I use my machine to develop quite a few .NET 3.5 applications.

Will I be able to uninstall the framework and Vs 2010 without problems or incompatibilities? Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, yes, though not explicitly guaranteed.

I wouldn't worry about it, though.  I've been doing it since Beta 1 with absolutely no problems, active 3.5 development happening on the same machine at the same time all the way.

In fact, I'm installing the RC on my main work machine (Vista x86) right now.

Comment: Ha!  If you think the uninstall takes forever, wait for the install!  ;)  It's worth it, though.  :)

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4 runs along side 2.0 (with 3.5 extensions) so shouldn't be an issue to install and remove without impacting your existing installation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it? Yes, probably. I do it.

Is it safe? No, it's not released software. There's a reason Microsoft offers no support of it.

There are no guarantees. Just because I can do it doesn't mean that you can do it, and if it destroys your ability to develop 3.5 applications, Microsoft is not required to help you in any way. You install any pre-release software on your own risk.

Comment: What I mean is, will I still be able to use VS 2008 without problems? Same answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

"Release Candidate" means, "if nobody reports serious bugs, we're going to release it". If it didn't work side by side with VS2008, that would be a serious bug. You should decide how important it is to you to be the one to report that bug.